# Careers 2.0 Search Function: Why is Joel Score not included as a search filter?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search, joel-test

Right now, for job seekers in Career 2.0,  it looks like they can choose the following  filters:

- what
- where
- distance (use slider) 20 miles

- Only telecommute jobs
- Only jobs offering relocation

---

I am aware that companies can opt to not reveal their Joel Test Score in the posting, but for those that do, it would be nice if this was available as a filtering option for job seekers.

Was this debated previously and I missed it?

The Joel Test Score is something I have not seen anywhere else on the web. As I contemplate my next career move, it is something I would definitely take into account. In fact, I would probably give a Joel test result more weight than any of the other current search filters, because it gives a lot of clues as what my quality of work life would be like at that company as well as the company culture.

In the Search section, how hard would it be to add a checkbox with label like "JoelTest Publicized" to the list?

Comment: I think that the [Joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) is somewhat outdated - there have been suggestions to [update it](http://geekswithblogs.net/btudor/archive/2009/06/16/132842.aspx), but I have not seen a consensus on what would make a good one.