# Let me filter jobs by the employer's Joel Test Scores

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs, joel-test

Can we have a filter to hide job postings without a certain Joel Test Score or certain Joel Test Score items checked off?

Basically, I don't want to have to sift through jobs without their Joel Test Score visible, a low test score, or certain items not checked.

For, example, there are two filters on the right hand side for: "Work remotely", "Offers relocation", we can add "Passes Joel Test with 9+", or "Shows Joel Test Results"

If not can we have this as a premium option?

Rough possible mockup:

> [image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Careers 2.0 Search Function: Why is Joel Score not included as a search filter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144070/careers-2-0-search-function-why-is-joel-score-not-included-as-a-search-filter)

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Given that this question has an answer and that one doesn't, it should be closed as a dupe of *this* question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wish I could convince the team to remove the Joel Test score from job listings.  I certainly do not support making it a search filter.  Why?  Not all of the items in the test are particularly applicable to all forms of development (especially web development) and some tests are more important than others for different developer styles.

The truth is, trusting an arbitrary score that isn't tailored to your specific needs is not going to help you find the right job for you.  An 11 might as well be a 0 if you absolutely require quiet working conditions to work effectively.  A 3 might be just fine if you want to be the second developer and 3rd employee of a start up.

Don't use the Joel score as a filter in your job search.  Use it as a collection of questions to help you think about whether a job would be a good fit for you and ask the most important questions for you in the interview if the work you'll be doing sounds interesting.

Comment: Why can't you convince the team?  Joel specifically states this feature is for separating the non-professional from the professional shops. I agree with what you've said to a point.  Some people just want to show up to work, make a bit of money and then go home to their family. Some people need constant improvement in their lives.  Some people need the filter, and some people like you don't. Your viewpoint to remove it is egocentric. Not having the feature seems like a cop out to get more job postings. It is not arbitrary, the questions are founded on top of Software Engineering science.

Comment: And I also do not agree with finding a job based on "interesting". Work exists because it is hard and something that needs to be done to improve society, usually by specialized people.  What I find interesting is learning, meeting people, conversing, experimenting, adventuring, and having fun with people, not work. Work is work, not fun play time.  Why else would we be working then? Just go home if work doesn't feel like work, is my opinion :)

Comment: @DerekLitz I think the data is valuable; the sum number is not valuable to _anyone_.  I specifically state to use this data, and if we can answer some of those questions for you up front, all the better.  Assuming this is totally necessary information, we do a horrible job of displaying it, because where it lies, the first thing you should do is check the score (at the bottom of the listing) if it has your important values before reading anything else.

Comment: Your second comment is just trolling.

Comment: Saying what I truly feel is trolling?  Just because you do not understand where my opinion is coming from, does not mean I am trolling. It has been studied that developer productivity varies from 1x-10x, and these studies are old. If anything that gap is widening as tools are created for different types of people because demand is so high for this type of work. Easier tools are being invented and more efficient tools are being invented and the easy tools are often not the most efficient tools. If anything __your__ comment was trolling, offensive to me, and certainly not founded upon.

Comment: Do you not believe that some people would rather achieve at least the 10x productivity (possibly more) then take longer breaks, rather then have a ton of fun at work?  I know the the latter exists, I am not saying it doesn't.  But you seem the claim the former does not.

Comment: That is exactly what I do, I check the score, and I check a to see if a few I really need are satisfied. I agree the score by itself might not be the best thing to filter on, but it is better then nothing.  I was getting fed up scrolling to the bottom and seeing no scores at all, over and over again.  The bottom is not that bad for usability, it is easy to scroll to the bottom and bounce back to the top.  Most people are probably like yourself, and care more about reading the job posting.  So your design is correct IMO.

Comment: @Derek so you seriously think that  fulfilling the Joel Test score *automatically* equates 10x productivity? And that companies that don't fulfill it are automatically less productive, and "fun" oriented? That's an incredibly narrow view of a very complex and diverse profession. The Joel Test should be *supporting data*, not a filter criterion. Just like high SO reputation *can* be supporting data when evaluating a candidate's competence - but it's far from being a reliable metric. If you put too much emphasis on metrics, people will optimize for those metrics - with often craptacular results

Comment: ... that said, on the other hand, if a user absolutely *wants* to filter out employers that don't publish their Joel Test (as silly as that may be), why not let them.

Comment: @Pëkka That is absolutely not what I am saying.  I am referencing a study and defending my ideals that this information is valuable for someone who can achieve 10x productivity and do not want to be burdened by environments that do not suit them.  Of course, I have fun while at work, usually conversing while I'm on break or at a meeting!  Not when I am doing my actual work.  It is complicated, I agree.  My viewpoint is certainly not narrow, but feel free to attack away :)  I do believe that MOST places that do not do things will be less productive.  It depends more on the people...

Comment: and good people will do the things in the Joel Test, IMHO.

Comment: @Pekka - because if you put it in, people will think it's important.  Actually, a better bet would be something like an OKCupid preference-matching thing.  As part of your profile, you declare which of the questions are critical to you, which are of moderate importance, which are of some importance, and which you don't care about (possibly even letting you say that you explicitly *don't* want one or more of them).  Then let it do a quick calculation on how well the opening in question fits *you*, and let you filter on *that* score.  Of course, this is more effort, and more processing cycles.

Comment: @BenBarden Good design idea, Ben, but it seems the feature is declined already :(

Comment: @DerekLitz `good people will do the things in the Joel Test, IMHO` I don't disagree - but still, blindly filtering by that metric is silly IMO. I bet there are work environments where huge amounts of money are thrown at developers but bureaucracy still prevents them from doing any actual work. It's a *strong indicator* of a potentially good employer, but it's nothing more than that.

Comment: @Ben *that* would really be the best way to go. For example, "I want to see only employers that use source control." That sounds like a reasonable requirement... as are all the other points in the Joel Test, but not if just viewed as a "x out of 12" quantity.

Comment: @DerekLitz "and good people will do the things in the Joel Test, IMHO." - are you saying that it's a significant indicator of morality?  Are you saying that the Joel-Test-Positive answer is the better answer in all circumstances?  I'm not sure quite what you're saying here, but it seems deeply suspect.  Please clarify?

Comment: @Pëkka It depends on the person.  Some developer's could care less about the money, like myself.  Not that I am going to sell myself short :)

Comment: @Pëkka not exactly.  As it turns out, 99% everyone who has ever filled out the joel test (on a posted job) has marked that they use source control.  So that's adding useless filtering to the search interface.

Comment: @Derek so a shop that you define as "good" may be a small team, with super competent people who love their craft, but perhaps not always able to buy the the most expensive tools on the market (who defines "best" tools anyway?), costing them one point on the Joel Test scale. See why it's not a useful metric for all situations and requirements?

Comment: @BenBarden Oh, yeah bad choice of words... I meant by good as in wanting to produce the most value for their time.  But that is wrong... everyone does that just some need certain environments and produce less with with their time despite exerting just as much effort.  I suppose I meant that companies that allow and support all of what the Joel Test has to offer will better support diverse groups of people, including, but not limited to high performance individuals who value that stuff highly.  Thanks for calling that one out :)

Comment: @Derek yeah, I don't disagree with that assumption. Nor with the idea that the Joel Test is useful. I don't think anyone wants to work for a place that doesn't use Version Control. I'm just against codifying it into a filter, because that suggests a place with a score of 12 is *automatically* and *inherently* better and more productive than one with 9. ... but the request of filtering out shops that don't publish their results at all, I can get behind. :)

Comment: @Pëkka That is the best argument for not having the filter I've seen.  We certainly do not want to exclude companies that are a good fit for some people outright. So the real question is: How do we cater to people who care about the Joel Test, people who do not, and companies who do not pass the Joel Test (and we want to because they all add value in the end), without communicating that the Joel Test is all important?

Comment: Only 37% of our job listings created in the past year answered questions on the Joel test. So attempting to filter on it would automatically exclude 63% of all jobs (and thousands of companies). The data doesn't support the notion that companies which don't fill it out are a bad fit. What it would more likely do is trick you into believing the results are more relevant to you, when they probably aren't, and that is a good reason not to provide the feature. Essentially we would be making it more difficult for you to find a job, while, ironically, making you feel like we're being helpful.

Comment: @BretCopeland One could argue this is a symptom of the demand versus supply, especially of leaders in positions of power to make change.  But yeah, thanks for the explanations of why this feature is not ready for prime time.  I'd urge to continue to monitor that.  I think it will be a good sign if 63% gets lower and lower over time :)  Do you have any of that data?

Comment: @BretCopeland Seems like it might be valuable to motivate companies to fill out the test, if you could do it without turning them off int eh first place.  Problem is that its initial form is as extra work for uncertain gain - and people who are trying to sell something (like a job opening) are not naturally inclined to spend additional effort taking tests that may make them look bad.

Comment: @DerekLitz I could run the numbers year to year or month to month if you'd like, but I know that in the last year 37% filled it out, but for all time it's about 41% suggesting that it might be trending downward.

Comment: @BenBarden we do outreach to companies in order to try to help them improve their job listings, and the Joel Test is certainly something we could push. The question is whether it is really that useful. As has been pointed out, many of the questions are either a given (source control), or not relevant to all environments (hallway usability testing, when you're team is remote). The fact that we publish a score which implies a ranking system may even discourage companies from posting when they can't check 10-12 of the boxes, even though they might have checked the one most important to you.

Comment: @BretCopeland hmm, trending downward? This __is__ complicated. Could be new blood, education differences, new generation, companies that value consistency and reliability over the productive developer who is prone to burn out if not tailored to :) Big corps don't like big spikes in productivity good or bad. Also, maybe companies are beginning to suspect it is not important or even detrimental to their job posting. Interesting, now I am certain I do not know if the Joel Test will die out or continue to be important to the software industry in the future, despite it remaining important to me :(

Comment: @BretCopeland Someone can still do hallway usability testing in a way. Perhaps change the terminology so it's not taken literally. But a better example would be what if your in an environment where usability is not even important, or a least not testable in that way. Am I suddenly supporting removing it? :_(  But it is just one point, I hope companies realize that!

Comment: @NickLarsen I think I understand your post a bit better, but perhaps tone down your opinion and maybe emphasize that, "Regardless of the Joel Test, you're going to have to do the footwork to find a good fit", which I think is what you were getting at in the last paragraph.  It was the word "interesting" that threw me off, "if the work you'll be doing sounds like a good fit", may be better.  This is why communicating in person is so much better ;)